# How to get the same data.frame with Data.Frame in pandas module of python?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

In R ,we can get the two data.frame such as x and y.

```
> x=data.frame(matrix(1:12,nrow=2,byrow=TRUE))
> y=data.frame(matrix(1:12,nrow=2,byrow=FALSE))
> x
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  7  8  9 10 11 12
> y
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  1  3  5  7  9 11
2  2  4  6  8 10 12
>
```

How to get the same  data.frame with Data.Frame in pandas module of python, to get x and y with  Data.Frame in pandas module of python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,13).reshape(2,-1))
>>> y = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,13).reshape(-1,2).T)

>>> x
   0  1  2   3   4   5
0  1  2  3   4   5   6
1  7  8  9  10  11  12

>>> y
   0  1  2  3   4   5
0  1  3  5  7   9  11
1  2  4  6  8  10  12
```

Comment: To add a line `import numpy as np` ,please.